# Click on anchor tag in javascript works on in console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have few anchor tag like following

`<a href="#" id="anchor tag id" class="pointer-level">Button</a>`

After page loads, the all anchor tag which has id of "**GTid_3**" should be triggered (click event). I wrote a jquery code

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    })

    $('.pointer-level').each(function(){    
        if($(this).attr("id")=="GTid_3")    
            $(this).click()
    })
</script>
```

This does not work if I included within `<script></script>` tag. But if I paste it in **console** (developer option), its working fine. This makes me mad. I couldnot understand why it does not when included in the page. Is there any event called when we work in console?

Comment: first of all you can't have multiple `a` tags with same ID, if needed change that to `data-id`, and to trigger click it should be `.trigger("click")`

Comment: is your `GTid_3` id adding dynamically to the elements?

Comment: try to include the script inside `$(document).ready(function(){` than having it outside

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're running your code before the elements are being created. You can also easily debug it with `console.log`s, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.pointer-level').each(function(){    
         console.log('.pointer-level found');
        if($(this).attr("id")=="GTid_3") {
            console.log('#GTid3 found!');
            $(this).click()
        }
    })
})
```

You didn't mention where exactly you are putting that `<script>`, but if the same code exactly works through the console, it also needs to work in action.

Comment: I put all script at the end of the page. I couldn't clearly understand why its working in console?

Comment: @varman Well, if you this code is being run by the JS engine **before** the `.pointer-level` div is being rendered, or in case the IDs are being generated by code, then when this code is running there might not be `#GTid3`! nothing will happen! Did you try use the script I wrote here? Could you tell me if the console had any output

Comment: As all said, id should be unique in some situation, here id-s are generated by the code. So the does code work in console because of auto generated?

Comment: If ids are generated by code, you have to make sure that ^ this code runs **after** the ids are assigned, or else jQuery will fail to find them.

Comment: Thank you so much, i got it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `$(document).find('.pointer-level').each(function()` if your ids adding dynamically. And for triggering click use `$(this).trigger('click')`

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).find('.pointer-level').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "GTid_3")
      $(this).trigger('click');
  });
})
$(document).on('click', '#GTid_3', function() {
  console.log('clicked '+$(this).text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="pointer-level" id="GTid_3">1</a>
<a class="pointer-level">2</a>
<a class="pointer-level" id="GTid_3">3</a>
<a class="pointer-level">4</a>
<a class="pointer-level" id="GTid_3">5</a>
```